# Is the expression 'I welcome you' very formal?

Tags: phrase-usage, idiomatic-language

Is the expression 'I welcome you' very formal? So formal as to be specifically used in some solemn rituals? At least, I've never seen it used in a daily conversation. I read this dialogue and got confused.

There's an upcoming squad tournament, Marchosias's teammates got severe injury and can't participate in it, so Elyan invited Marchosias to join his team. Marchosias accepted the invitation, and here came the dialogue.

> Marchosias: I, Arthur Marchosias, hereby request to transfer into Team Crimson.
> Elyan: I welcome you, Arthur Marchosias.

The dialogue seems quite formal, they even used the full name. It just sounds like some knight ritual or some holy ritual in church. A single word 'welcome' doesn't fit the atmosphere here, right?

Comment: If the injured person being replaced was [one of] Marchosias's teammates, it sounds as if he was already a member! Presumably the formality of the dialogue is meant to imitate what you call a 'knight ritual'.

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks! Though the situation was, the rest of Marchosias's team was injured, Marchosias couldn't solo a squad, and it happened that Elyan's team needed one more warrior. So, Elyan invited Marchosias to his team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialogue seems formal judging by the word choice: hereby, to request, to transfer, to welcome. And they address each other by full name, as you've noted.

I daresay the meaning of "welcome" here leans more towards "accept, approve" ([3](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/welcome)) than towards "greet" ([1](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/welcome)).

Compare

> I welcome you, Arthur Marchosias. (*I gladly accept your request, sir*)
>
> Welcome to the team, Arthur. (as a less formal and more cordial greeting)

Answer (score 1):

It's not formal as such, but probably not something normally said between individuals. It is more likely to be used when addressing an audience or crowd by someone such as a master of ceremonies, compare or speaker. For example *"I welcome you to tonight's festivities / show / meeting"*.
When addressing an individual *"Welcome to my house"* is more likely.